# Parse json with pig/hive

Tags: json, apache-pig

I am trying to parse a json file using pig but I am not getting the expected result. I am very close but somehow I am not able to get the result.

This is my input json file

```
$ cat example.json
{ "food":"Tacos", "person": [{"Name": "Alice","Age": 26},{"Name": "Jasper","Age": 28}],"amount":30 }
```

This is the result I am expecting

```
$ cat result.txt
food,person.name,person.age,amount
Tacos,Alice,26,30
Tacos,Jasper,28,30
```

and this is what I tried till now

```
$ cat example.pig
REGISTER 'elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';
REGISTER 'elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';
A = LOAD 'example.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-    nestedLoad');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN($0#'person');
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN($0) AS MYMAP;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE MYMAP#'Name',MYMAP#'Age';
DUMP D;
```

and after running this script I get this output

```
(Alice,26)
(Jasper,28)
```

How do I extract the first and the last key/value pair?

Comment: what does "describe A" tell you ?

Comment: @Amit, describe A says "Schema for A unknown."

Comment: Okay, Without known schema, I am not sure how much I can help. Let us try using dump A". What does it show you ?